# Magento 2: How to exclude/hide products from Search?

Tags: magento2, category, frontend, products, catalogsearch

I still want to be able to access to some products through the URL but exclude them from the Search bar

I am using elasticsearch7

Thank you in advance

EDIT:

Ideally, to do it programmatically

Comment: mark them out of stock and then when user visits those url then redirect it to the catg page in which product belongs..let me know if that could do the work for you then i will share the code with you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In admin product page, set the visibility attribute value to 'Catalog'.**

-> You product will be accessible through category pages and direct url but not through search.

Other values of visibility attribute :

- Not Visible Individually : Only accessible through direct url
- Search : Only accessible through search and direct url
- Catalog, Search : Accessible through all ways

Answer (score 0):

you can set product to not include by setting up individual product visibility option.

refer below screenshot

[image]