# Magento2.4.6 fails to override CatalogSearch

Tags: magento2.4.6

I rewrote the `Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\CollectionFactory` using **magento2.4.6** so that the sort of product page can work normally.

As of version 2.4.4, I successfully rewrote using the following rules in **di.xml**:

```
<preference for="elasticsearchCategoryCollection" type="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection"/>
<preference for="elasticsearchFulltextSearchCollection" type="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection"/>
<preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection"
            type="myvendor\CompFramework\Collection"/>
<virtualType name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\CollectionFactory" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="instanceName" xsi:type="string">myvendor\CompFramework\Collection</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Is there any way to rewrite
`vendor/magento/module-catalogsearch/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection.php`? Or is there any way to solve the problem that the product cannot be searched? Thanks

Comment: But the current product page cannot load the product, and it shows we can't find products matching the selection

Answer (score 0):

To make a product unsearchable you can update the product **visibility** attribute to **Catalog** only.
In that way, the product will appear on the category page and product direct URL (PDP Page) but will not appear on the search page.

Please check this answer
[Magento 2: How to exclude/hide products from Search?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319614/magento-2-how-to-exclude-hide-products-from-search)